# Cast constexpr int[] to void*

Tags: c++

I have a static array of integers that I never want to change. I have a C-style function that wants to have this array as a void-pointer parameter. I am trying out different combinations of const_cast and reinterpret_cast, but I'm coming to the point where I have no clue of what I'm exactly doing and it keeps giving me errors.

```
class Foo
{
    static constexpr int bar[3] = {1,2,3};

    void method()
    {
        cfunction(reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast<int*>(&bar)));
    }
};
```

> invalid const_cast from type 'const int (*)[3]' to type 'int*'

I see that it fails because the types don't match. I also tried `const_cast<int[]>(bar)`, but `const_cast` wants to have a pointer or reference type.

Where can I read up on this subject? It's hard for me to understand what is going on here.

Comment: Honestly, dont do that. What if your function tries to change the array? If you cant change the function, dont make the array const

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis should be equivalent.

Comment: @Yastanub No, the first one is the pointer, the second one the adress of the pointer

Comment: `cfunction((int*)bar);`

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis the answer section is below ;)

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis no it is not `&functionname` is equivalent to `functionname` the `&` is optional

Comment: @Yastanub for functions yes, but bar is not a function.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis oh i somehow misread the question i dont knwo why i thought it was about function pointers sry :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cfunction((void*)bar);
```

P.S. I 've seen lots of programmers struggling to use all these casts when, in reality, they only need the simple C cast. If you insist on the C++ cast style, then

```
cfunction(reinterpret_cast<void*>(const_cast<int*>(bar)));
```

(Remove the & from bar).

Comment: should be `void*` but i think it doesnt matter

Comment: This works, but there one caveat. I have enabled -Werrors, so I will get a non-solvable warning here. Are there any alternatives?

Comment: What is the warning?

Comment: `warning: use of old-style cast [-Wold-style-cast]` and `warning: cast from type 'const int*' to type 'void*' casts away qualifiers [-Wcast-qual]`

Comment: The warning is correct. Either you disable it at the specific point (VS has a #pragma warning to do that), or you fix the function to want a const int*, not a void.

Comment: I 've added a C++ style one.

Comment: Okay, so I was actually pretty close. Do you have some references for me so I can learn more about this kind of stuff?

Comment: It depends on how do you want to immerse into C++. [book list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: Do you mean by *"in reality, they only need the simple C cast"* that I should always just use the *"simple C cast"*?

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler says, `&bar` is a `const int (*)[3]` - a pointer to an array - and you can't `const_cast` that to an `int*`.

You want a pointer to the array's first element, not to the array.
That is,

```
const_cast<int*>(&bar[0])
```

or, equivalently,

```
const_cast<int*>(bar)
```

Of course, this will only be valid if the C function doesn't ever modify the array.
If there is any risk of that, you should not make it const.

Answer (score 2):

If the C function was promising to not modify the data, then it would be taking a `const void*`. Since it doesn't, it might modify it. So don't make your array `const`:

```
class Foo
{
    static int bar[3];

    void method()
    {
        cfunction(bar);
    }
};
```

And define the array in the `.cpp` file of your class:

```
int Foo::bar[3] = {1, 2, 3};
```